# Why is read.csv so slow?

Tags: r, csv

Having browsed the questions on stackoverflow for a long time and found many answers useful I have finally come across something that I couldn't find an answer for. It's also about time I signed up to start giving something back to the community as and when I come across a question I can meaningfully contribute to (that's for another day perhaps).

Anyway, my first stackoverflow question, so please be gentle with me:

I am well aware that the read.csv function in R is by no means the most efficient way of reading data in, many questions and answers concern alternatives to read.csv but the focus of this question is slightly different and I suppose there are really two questions being asked.

1. What I want to know is why read.csv is so slow? What are the overheads that contribute to its poor performance?
2. In addition I have the fortune of a number of computers I can test bits of code on, including a laptop with a SSD and a desktop with standard HDD, in recent tests I have not been able to find a discernible difference between the read times on either machine ( I would have expected a much faster read time using solid state drive), why might this be the case?

Some code to reproduce the sort of benchmark that I have been testing:

```
    bm_io = function (runs = 3, n = 1e6, ncol = 1000) {
      set.seed(1)
      on.exit(set.seed(NULL))
      x = rnorm(n)
      m = data.frame(matrix(x, ncol = ncol))
      timings = data.frame(user = numeric(2 * runs), system = 0, 
                   elapsed = 0, test = c("write", "read"))
      for (i in 1:runs) {
        fname = tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
        fname = "temp.csv"
        invisible(gc())
        timings[2 * i - 1, 1:3] = system.time({
          write.csv(m, fname, row.names = FALSE)
        })[1:3]
        timings[2 * i, 1:3] = system.time({
          read.csv(fname)
        })[1:3]
        unlink(fname)
      }
      timings
    }
```

I would appreciate any ones thoughts or comments on this, in addition if I have missed a similar question, please feel free to point me in the correct direction. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

A considerable performance boost is the parameter `colClasses`. The performance boost is typically a factor of two.

What I typically do in my code reading large csv files is the following procedure:

- read the first couple of rows using `nrows`
- extract the classes from the columns of the read data frame
- load the entire data frame with extracted classes using `colClasses`
- if this fails due to unforeseen data use the entire data without `colClasses`

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to respond. I am aware that there are numerous arguments to `read.csv` that would improve the performance. Although none of them get close to something like `fread` from the `data.table` package. My question is more about what it is that makes `read.csv` so slow compared to some of the alternatives, and why I would not see a difference when reading from a SSD or a HDD as I would expect.